# Replacing empty csv column values with a zero

Tags: python, csv, list

So I'm dealing with a csv file that has missing values.
What I want my script to is:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import csv
import sys

#1. Place each record of a file in a list.
#2. Iterate thru each element of the list and get its length.
#3. If the length is less than one replace with value x.


reader = csv.reader(open(sys.argv[1], "rb"))
for row in reader:
    for x in row[:]:
                if len(x)< 1:
                         x = 0
                print x
print row
```

Here is an example of data, I trying it on, ideally it should work on any column lenghth

```
Before:
actnum,col2,col4
xxxxx ,    ,
xxxxx , 845   ,
xxxxx ,    ,545

After
actnum,col2,col4
xxxxx , 0  , 0
xxxxx , 845, 0
xxxxx , 0  ,545
```

Any guidance would be appreciated

Update Here is what I have now (thanks):

```
reader = csv.reader(open(sys.argv[1], "rb"))
for row in reader:
    for i, x in enumerate(row):
                if len(x)< 1:
                         x = row[i] = 0
print row
```

However it only seems to out put one record, I will be piping the output to a new file on the command line.

Update 3: Ok now I have the opposite problem, I'm outputting duplicates of each records.
Why is that happening?

```
After
actnum,col2,col4
actnum,col2,col4
xxxxx , 0  , 0
xxxxx , 0  , 0
xxxxx , 845, 0
xxxxx , 845, 0
xxxxx , 0  ,545
xxxxx , 0  ,545
```

Ok I fixed it (below) thanks you guys for your help.

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import csv
import sys

#1. Place each record of a file in a list.
#2. Iterate thru each element of the list and get its length.
#3. If the length is less than one replace with value x.


reader = csv.reader(open(sys.argv[1], "rb"))
for row in reader:
    for i, x in enumerate(row):
                if len(x)< 1:
                         x = row[i] = 0
    print ','.join(str(x) for x in row)
```

Comment: The reason you only print one line is that your print statement is outside of the for loop - indent it once, and you should be fine.

Comment: You can replace "if len(x) <1:" with " if x.strip():".  "" will evaluate to False, and any string value will evaulate to True (including spaces).

Comment: In your update you removed the `print` statement within the loop where  you really wanted to remove the one outside the loop. You may also wish to strip your strings, as per my answer below.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change your code:

```
for row in reader:
    for x in row[:]:
                if len(x)< 1:
                         x = 0
                print x
```

into:

```
for row in reader:
    for i, x in enumerate(row):
                if len(x)< 1:
                         x = row[i] = 0
                print x
```

Not sure what you think you're accomplishing by the `print`, but the key issue is that you need to modify `row`, and for that purpose you need an index into it, which `enumerate` gives you.

Note also that all other values, except the empty ones which you're changing into the number `0`, will remain strings.  If you want to turn them into `int`s you have to do that explicitly.

Answer (score 1):

You are **very** nearly there!

There are just a couple of small bugs.

- `len(x)< 1` will not work for the second column in the second row of your data because `x` will contain `'    '` (and have a length > 1). You'll need to `strip` your strings.
- `print row` will probably print an empty list because you've finished iterating. You can probably just remove this line.

Also: Are you trying to modify the file or just output the corrections to pipe to some other file or process?