# Writing output to csv file [in correct format]

Tags: python, python-3.x

I realize this question has been asked a million times and there is a lot of documentation on it. However, I am unable to output the results in the correct format.

The below code was adopted from: [Replacing empty csv column values with a zero](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2862709/replacing-emty-csv-column-values-with-a-zero)

```
# Save below script as RepEmptyCells.py 
# Add #!/usr/bin/python to script 
# Make executable by chmod +x prior to running the script on desired .csv file 

# Below code will look through your .csv file and replace empty spaces with 0s
# This can be particularly useful for genetic distance matrices 

import csv
import sys

reader = csv.reader(open(sys.argv[1], "rb"))
for row in reader:
    for i, x in enumerate(row):
                if len(x)< 1:
                         x = row[i] = 0
    print(','.join(int(x) for x in row))
```

Currently, to get the correct output .csv file [i.e. in correct format] one can run the following command in bash:

```
 #After making the script executable        
./RepEmptyCells.py input.csv > output.csv # this produces the correct output
```

I've tried to use `csv.writer` function to produce the correctly formatted `output.csv` file (similar to `./RepEmptyCells.py input.csv > output.csv`) without much luck.

I'd like to learn how to add this last part to the code to automate the process without having to do it in bash.

What I have tried:

```
f = open(output2.csv, 'w') 

import csv
import sys

reader = csv.reader(open(sys.argv[1], "rb"))
for row in reader:
    for i, x in enumerate(row):
                if len(x)< 1:
                         x = row[i] = 0
    f.write(','.join(int(x) for x in row)) 

f.close()
```

When looking at the raw files from this code and the one before, they look the same.

However, when I open them in either excel or iNumbers the latter (i.e. `output2.csv`) shows only a single row of the data.

Its important that both `output.csv` and `output2.csv` can be opened in excel.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

2 options:

1. Just do a `f.write('\n')` after your current `f.write` statement.
2. Use `csv.writer`. You mention it but it isn't in your code.

   ```
   writer = csv.writer(f)
   ...
   writer.writerow([int(x) for x in row])  # Note difference in parameter format
   ```

Comment: Thanks. That did it! So you just had to add new line ('/n')! 1) works. 2) still doesn't, but that's okay.

Comment: Beware, I'm surprised 1) works, as on Unix '\n' will translate to LF, while I was pretty sure Excel will only accept csv files when they end on CRLF. In fact, this is a feature of the CSV format, a single LF denotes a line break inside a cell. That's why you open the files as 'rb' for Python 2 and newline='' for Python 3, because the csv writer handles this specific aspect and would be disturbed by the default newline abstraction of Python.

Answer (score 1):

An humble proposition

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import csv
import sys

# Use with statement to properly close files
# Use newline='' which is the right option for Python 3.x
with open(sys.argv[1], 'r', newline='') as fin, open(sys.argv[2], 'w', newline='') as fout:
    reader = csv.reader(fin)
    # You may need to redefine the dialect for some version of Excel that 
    # split cells on semicolons (for _Comma_ Separated Values, yes...)
    writer = csv.writer(fout, dialect="excel")
    for row in reader:
        # Write as reading, let the OS do the caching alone
        # Process the data as it comes in a generator, checking all cells
        # in a row. If cell is empty, the or will return "0"
        # Keep strings all the time: if it's not an int it would fail
        # Converting to int will force the writer to convert it back to str
        # anwway, and Excel doesn't make any difference when loading.
        writer.writerow( cell or "0" for cell in row )
```

Sample `in.csv`

```
1,2,3,,4,5,6,
7,,8,,9,,10
```

Output `out.csv`

```
1,2,3,0,4,5,6,0
7,0,8,0,9,0,10
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import csv
import sys

with open(sys.argv[1], 'rb') as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f)
    for row in reader:
        print row.replace(' ', '0')
```

and I don't understand your need for using the shell and redirecting.
a csv writer is just:

```
with open('output.csv', 'wb') as f:
    writer = csv.writer(f)
    writer.writerows(rows)
```